# Как правильно написать выражение с оператором OR?

Tags: python

Как правильно написать выражение с оператором OR в этом случае:

```
if int(requests.get(url).status_code) in range(200, 299) or in range (400, 499):
    ...
```

Comment: Кстати, обратите внимание, что range (200,299) не включает 299. То же самое и range(400, 499).

Answer (score 8):

я бы делал это так:

```
r = requests.get(url)
if 200 <= r.status_code <= 299 or 400 <= r.status_code <= 499:
    ...
```

Answer (score 7):

Вот так правильно:

```
code = int(requests.get(url).status_code)
if 200 <= code <= 299 or 400 <= code <= 499:
```

Answer (score 3):

```
code = int(requests.get(url).status_code)
if code in range(200, 299) or code in range (400, 499):
```